# Write Html code In aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have whole page HTML in my database and i want write that html code in to an aspx page.
Means it replace old html code from new one.

Is there any other way to write html code in to aspx page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Id.InnerHtml = "html code";

its worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Use **HttpHandler** to do this. Just read the HTML page from the database and flush it to response stream.

Be sure to map the handler with a route in web.config

### CODE: PageWriter HttpHanlder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for PageWriter
/// </summary>
public class PageWriter : IHttpHandler
{
    public PageWriter()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string htmlPageFromDatabase = string.Empty;

            //Read the HTML Page content into htmlPageFromDatabase from database

            context.Response.Write(htmlPageFromDatabase);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("Page could not be loaded due to " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

### WEB.CONFIG

```
<httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add path="PageFromDatabase.aspx" verb="GET" type="PageWriter" />
</httpHandlers>
```

After this, You cann access your page from http://yourserver/yourapp/PageFromDatabase.aspx  [ ex: http://localhost/mywebsite/PageFromDatabase.aspx ]

Comment: can please give me link or any example for this

Answer (score 2):

You could put an <asp:Literal ...> control on the page and set the Text property to be the text from the database.

Or if you really what the whole page contents to come from a database, you could create an .ashx HttpHandler and do a Response.Write() to write the HTML back to the response stream. Something like this should work:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    int id = 0;

    if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["id"], out id);

    if (id != 0)
    {
        var con = new SqlConnection("myconnectionstring");
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT html FROM mytable WHERE id = @id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("id", id);

        object html = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (html != null)
            context.Response.Write(html);
    }
    else
        context.Response.Write("No content found");
}
```

Comment: can please give me link or any example for this

Comment: Consider that You will need to HtmlEncode the HTML content before you assign the HTML to Literal. or it will display row HTML upon assignment without HtmlEncode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string newHtml = "...";
Response.Clear();
Response.Write(newHtml);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of html is on the page? Does it have a masterpage? Why is there html on the page that you are replacing?

You could override the Render event of the page and write out the html.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write(newHtmlGoesHere);
}
```